# error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message connection timed out

Tags: netbeans, javadb

[image]I was trying to create a database in Netbeans, I have followed all the steps by starting the server and writing the username and passwords, but when it comes to creating the database, this message occurs:

[image: error]

What's the issue here?

here's the path:
java DB instalation:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\db
>   database location: 
>   C:\Users\Admin.netbeans-derby

Comment: what db server are you using? If it is sql server are you trying to connect to the default instance or a named instance?

Comment: yeah it's a SQL default instance server

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : show us how you want to create the database. Also you can look here and create it via service . [embedded-database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759252/querying-embedded-database-in-netbeans-using-derby/16764522#16764522)

Comment: @moskito I created it using the simple steps shown in this article.. everything is clear there.

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : Why you show us not this link ?

Comment: @moskito-x checkout the steps i showed in the image posted in the question :))

Comment: Can you connect to your `sample` Database ?

Comment: @moskito-x no i can't.. the same error occurs :(

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi :please look at my answer

Comment: @moskito-x yes it does look the same

Comment: actually i get this:
Mon Apr 28 02:22:01 SGT 2014 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Mon Apr 28 02:22:01 SGT 2014 : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.8.3.0 - (1405108) started and ready to accept connections on port 1527

Comment: @moskito-x this notification pops up: Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection timed out: connect.)

Comment: @moskito-x no i didn't find Sample when i browsed

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : In your posted Picture you tell us it is in `C:\Users\Admin\.netbeans-derby` Are you Admin ?

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : And now what folder are in `C:\Users\Admin\.netbeans-derby` ???

Comment: @moskito-x ohhh there's the sample folder in there!!

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : Have you read + write rights in that folder ? test it , create an `xyz` folder.

Comment: @moskito-x i can create the folder xyz without any problem

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : and now in my answer look at `Java DB Properties` The two properties `Java DB Installation` and `Database Location` pointing to the right folder ?

Comment: @moskito-x no they don't.. should i put both of them in the same path?

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : No, you should browse to the correct folders. One for the DB Installation folder. and the other to the Database folder.

Comment: @moskito-x u mean i should just leave them like that?? and how i can solve my problem?? it's really an urgent matter

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : you don't understand. Please put into your question the values of the 2 fields.

Comment: @moskito-x ok you can check my question now.. i have put the paths of both of them

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : look at your database location : really this : `C:\Users\Admin.netbeans-derby` or a typo ?

Comment: @moskito-x it's the same one.. .netbeans-derby not typo

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : So it's wrong must be `C:\Users\Admin\.netbeans-derby`   !!!

Comment: @moskito-x !!! it's the one you wrote just now in your comment C:\Users\Admin\.netbeans-derby

Comment: @Alladinsaoudi : So the path in your Question is wrong :(

Comment: @moskito-x ohhhhh yeah u'r right i'm really sorry..the path in the question is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Can you right click on sample Database -> Properties

looks like this ?

[image]

and after stop and start the server you get : look for port 1527

[image]

**can you test the following**

[image]

**and new connection wizzard**

[image]

Browse to your Database folder and look if there exists `sample`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After double clicking on sample DB, having successfully connected to the sample DB, I have got the app deployed successfully. I think it is some bug or a 'feature'. I think it may help somebody.